# Adding different pop-up iframes to multiple points

Tags: r, iframe, r-leaflet, r-mapview

I'm building a map using the mapview R package following
[this tutorial](https://environmentalinformatics-marburg.github.io/mapview/popups/html/popups.html). Adding a different image to each point using `popup=popupImage(images,src = "remote")` works fine.

The issue is with iframe popups.

The example using `popup = mapview:::popupIframe("https://www.youtube.com/embed/iApz08Bh53w?autoplay=1", width = 300, height = 225)` is only for a single point. If I combine several iframe video links (the same way shown with image links) adds *ALL video iframes* to each point.

How do I add a *different* iframe to each point?

Comment: I would use [googleway package](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway)

Comment: That googleway package looks awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how this can be done.

```
library(mapview)

# some example points
pts = breweries[1:2, ]

# some urls - note this cannot be a named list, javascript does not like names!
urls = list(
  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/iApz08Bh53w?autoplay=1",
  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/KEkrWRHCDQU?autoplay=1"
)

# create the popups
pop = lapply(urls, mapview:::popupIframe)

# et voila
mapview(pts, popup = pop)
```

The `popupIframe` function is currently not vectorised, hence we need to use `lapply` to create the popup objects in a list.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks Tim.